# Azure AD Sync - Default attribute synced and DirectoryExtension

Tags: azure-active-directory

Should be very simple, but I can't find an exact article anywhere.
Have been using Azure AD Sync for awhile, but never really know this part because I never set up from scratch. I guess I can do try and error, but the environment that I'm on, seems hard to allow me to do this.

**Default Attribute synced from Azure AD Sync tool**

Take example: proxyAddress attribute in AD. My current setup is this attribute is included to be synced in DirectoryExtension.

If I remove this from DirectoryExtension, will it still be synced to the actually proxyAddress in Azure AD?

or similar question:
Does extension synced from DirectoryExtension actually synced to a different attribute in Azure AD (extension_8xxxxxxxxxx_proxyAddresses)? and basic attribute (city, proxyAddress, mail) will be synced regardless of DirectoryExtension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out answer to my own questions.
Attribute added to DirectoryExtension is synced to a different attribute in Azure AD (*extension_8xxxxxx_aaaaa*)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized) is the complete sets of default attribute already synced without having to do anything in Azure AD Connect

Answer (score 0):

•   The schema and its attributes are of the same compatibility version in on-premises active directory and in the Azure active directory. As AAD is an extension of on-premises AD functionality in the cloud, thus it supports AD attribute synchronization for on-premises AD through Azure AD Connect tool for specific versions and editions of Windows Server builds.

•   Thus, windows server 2016 and later are recommended and preferred for on-premises active directory synchronization. Also, custom attributes that are created/added in the on-premises AD can be synced through AAD Connect and the same synced attributes will be added as an additional attribute other then the default attributes in Azure AD.

•   Also, the default attributes if in case are modified/changed to a new attribute name in the on-premises AD, then these changed/modified attributes are synced in AAD and the same changed/modified attributes are created during the synchronization process while leaving the default named attributes unchanged/undefined in AAD. Thus, it is not recommended to change/modify the default attributes of on-premises AD and rather than add custom attributes and synchronize them accordingly to AAD.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51121.active-directory-schema-update-and-custom-attribute.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/user-provisioning-sync-attributes-for-mapping

Comment: thanks @KartikBhiwapurkar-M. That's very helpful.
Actually I'm trying to find what is the default attribute synced when we install Azure AD Connect. And also what is the attribute in AAD that matched with the attribute that we add in DirectoryExtension ;)

Comment: The default attribute that is synced when the first Azure AD connect starts synchronization is the 'UPN - User Principal Name' and for the attribute that is matched with the one that we add in DirectoryExtension has to be one of User and group objects that too Single valued attributes and multi valued attributes